# How do I avoid a moving toolbar when the keyboard is open in a fullscreen activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app, when the keyboard is invoked, the toolbar is moved upwards. How do I prevent the toolbar from moving upwards?

Here's the code to make the activity full screen:

```java
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
```

Layout:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android=".."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_background">

        <include layout="@layout/layout_toolbar" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView.......>

    <RelativeLayout......>

    <EditText....><!--There are multiple EditTexts here.-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post your layout for more info

Comment: Layout:
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android=".."android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"><android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/toolbar_background"><include layout="@layout/layout_toolbar" /></android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout><ScrollView.......><RelativeLayout..><EditText....//here has multiple editText .</RelativeLayout>.

Comment: Could you please add it as an edit to your original question as a code block so that it is more readable

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in menifests for `Activity`

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: This will compress the layout which is not a proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your toolbar's root layout

> Most of the time, your app won’t need to draw under the status bar or
>   the navigation bar, but if you do: you need to make sure interactive
>   elements (like buttons) aren’t hidden underneath them. That’s what the
>   default behavior of the android:fitsSystemWindows="true" attribute
>   gives you: it sets the padding of the View to ensure the contents
>   don’t overlay the system windows.
>
> A few things to keep in mind:
>
> fitsSystemWindows is applied depth first — ordering matters: it’s the
>   first View that consumes the insets that makes a difference

from https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec

basically you're telling the toolbar not to move & stay on top & instead move the views underneath it upwards below it

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android=".."android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"><android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/toolbar_background"><include layout="@layout/layout_toolbar" /></android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout><ScrollView.......><RelativeLayout......><EditText....//here has multiple editText . when i tab last edittext keyboard is appeare and toolbar move up.</RelativeLayout>.

Comment: android:fitsSystemWindows="true" its not work for me

Comment: why is your appbarlayout inside a relativelayout?

Comment: My Activity in fullScreen mode I have scenario: scroll full UI except toolbar . bcz there need to move Complete Screen below toolbar that reason i write RelativeLayout as a parent layout

Comment: what is the link between fullscreen functionality and relativelayout? any layout can be made fullscreen, including appbarlayout(which is basically a fancy linearlayout)

Comment: bcz i need to scroll View behind toolbar layout that reason i am add relativlayout . linearlayout not give that functionallity . i attahed image how to scroll i nedd . plese see these

Comment: but My question is How to prevent move toolbar upward side in fullScreen Activity when keyboard invoke

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CollapsingToolBarLayout if it fits your UI requirement inside of the AppBarLayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:ripple="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:background="#fff"
           ripple:contentInsetStart="0dp">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```